# Chrome autofill without submitting form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

I have replaced my `<form>` and `<input type='submit'>` with jQuery, so I can send input data using Ajax rather than reloading the page.

This works great, however Chrome autofill stopped working, which I would need.

Simplified version of my current code:

```
<input type="text" id="field1">
<input type="button" id="send" value="Save">
```

handeled by jQuery:

```
$("#send").click(function () {
    $.post('my.php', {
        field1: field1
    });
});
```

How can I get Google to remember values typed in `field1`?

Comment: Are u using any php framework? If you're using Codeigniter then you can use <?php echo set_value('inputname'); ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an form with an submit button, so chrome can autofill the form and you can make a fallback for browsers with no javascript activated. You can check this when the `X-Requested-With` header has the value `XMLHttpRequest`.

You can for example send the json response for the ajax request and a html response for an older browser that doesnt requested the page via XHR.

Example jQuery-Code:

```
$("#myForm").on("submit",function(e) {
  // Prevent browser from submitting form
  e.preventDefault();

  if(everythingIsFine) {
     // Send form via ajax to the backend
     sendMyForm();
  } else {
    doSomeWarningsForUser();
  }
  
  
}
```

And your html like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/myAction/" id="myForm">
   <input type="text" id="field1">
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This work form me, but i've change order of code,  e.PreventDefault(); take place right after opening bracket of function :
$("#myForm").on("submit",function(e) {
e.preventDefault();  ...

Comment: @NovpiarEffendi While it should also work at the end of the function, because of the single threaded nature of JavaScript, but it definitely makes more sense mentally to move it to the first line. Adapted it. :)